# Best practice SQL table column with 2 values options

Tags: mysql

What's the best SQL practice for an SQL table where one column only has 2 values (saved as string).

Keep it as `varchar` (string will be recurring)? Use foreign key to another table that store these 2 values? Use a boolean?

Whats the better option and why?

Thanks

Comment: Either VARCHAR + according CHECK constraint or ENUM.

Comment: Only ever boolean ? using a separate table means you would have to read it thereby imposing a possibly tiny overhead

Answer (score -1):

There are no one 'the right one' answer. It depends on your needs and use cases, as usual.

**TL;DR**: use `ENUM`. `ENUM` and `TYNYINT(1)` can save you significant amount of the storage space on the huge tables and `ENUM` will return string in queries unlike `TYNYINT(1)`, but `ENUM` have some differences in sorting.

Here is some theory:

1. `VARCHAR` — will take [string length]+(1 or 2 bytes prefix) storage size per record and store string value as it is.
2. `TYNYINT(1)` (aka `BOOLEAN`) — will take 1 byte storage size per record and store only some number (-128 .. 127 `SIGNED` or 0 .. 255 `UNSIGNED`)
3. `ENUM` — will take 1 byte for set of values under 255 and 2 bytes for set of values under 65536 per record plus total size of all values + its indices once. (For case of two values if will be 1 byte per record and `LENGTH(val1) + LENGTH(val2) + 2` once)

So from the storage size sight `TYNYINT(1)` and `ENUM` almost the same and `VARCHAR` will produce additional downside for each record and can be significant for tables with millions records.

From the code sight when you SELECTing data `VARCHAR` and `ENUM` will be the same, because you will receive just that string value, but with `TYNYINT(1)` you should perform additional matching your number value into string lalue somewhere.
But you should apply additional checks when INSERTing data for `VARCHAR` and `TYNYINT(1)` because it will not limited by database and `ENUM` will be limited by the RDBM itself. (to be honest, with ENUM you still should apply checks if query was OK, but it's another topic)

From the SQL sight queries with `VARCHAR` and `TYNYINT(1)` columns will be the same, but `ENUM` will have some [limitations and differences](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html) (for example sorting performed based on their index numbers, which depend on the order in which the enumeration members were listed in the column specification).

From the supporting sight to add new value in the future with `VARCHAR` and `TYNYINT(1)` you should modify your application code more or less, depending on your application structure, and less with `ENUM`.